# Generate carrierwave file path when full object isn't available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave to upload images in my Rails 4 app. For example, a User can upload an avatar. All works fine so far, and I can generate the avatar image in my view by appending "_url" to the file field using

```
    @users.each do |user|
      user.avatar_url(:small)
    end
```

However, sometimes I don't have the User object available, for example when I'm just joining it like this:

```
    @listings = Listing.joins(:user).select("listings.*, user.avatar as avatar")
    #I know I could use :includes, but this isn't always practical in my app
```

Therefore I can't automatically generate the path, and have to rely on manually creating it in my view like this:

```
    <% if Rails.env.production? %>
              <%= image_tag("https://fullpath.com/uploads/user/avatar/#{listing.user_id}/small_#{listing.p_user_avatar}") %>
            <% else %>
              <%= image_tag("https://fullpath.com/uploads/user/avatar/#{listing.user_id}/small_#{listing.p_user_avatar}") %>
    <% end %>
```

Another option would be to write a helper to generate these urls, so at least they're in one place. But surely Carrierwave has a built-in way of dealing with this? How should I go about it?

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :avatar, UserAvatarUploader
    end

    class UserAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
      include CarrierWave::RMagick
      def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
      version :small do
        process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
        process :quality => 75
      end
      def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
      end
    end
```

Comment: It sounds like from the `@listing` you have at least the `user_id` so why not `User.find(listing.user_id).avatar_url(:small)` or something?

Comment: If im displaying a list of listings with a user (owner) image next to each one, I don't want to do User.find for each one, thats the N+1 queries problem. Can get around it with eager loading (.includes()) but thats not an option in this particular case